# Why is my program of game of fifteen printing '_' instead of the replaced number?

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I'm taking cs50 and on pset3 fifteen. The game looks fine except when inputing a number to replace '_' with. At the start when the game asks for a number/tile to move, I input the number for '_' to move to but it doesn't replace '_' with the chosen number. This only happens when dimensions are even and choosing the numbers to the left of '_' at the start of the game. Thanks!

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// constants
#define DIM_MIN 3
#define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

// dimensions
int d;

// prototypes
void clear(void);
void greet(void);
void init(void);
void draw(void);
bool move(int tile);
bool won(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: fifteen d\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // ensure valid dimensions
    d = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (d < DIM_MIN || d > DIM_MAX)
    {
        printf("Board must be between %i x %i and %i x %i, inclusive.\n",
            DIM_MIN, DIM_MIN, DIM_MAX, DIM_MAX);
        return 2;
    }

    // open log
    FILE *file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    // greet user with instructions
    greet();

    // initialize the board
    init();

    // accept moves until game is won
    while (true)
    {
        // clear the screen
        clear();

        // draw the current state of the board
        draw();

        // log the current state of the board (for testing)
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            {
                fprintf(file, "%i", board[i][j]);
                if (j < d - 1)
                {
                    fprintf(file, "|");
                }
            }
            fprintf(file, "\n");
        }
        fflush(file);

        // check for win
        if (won())
        {
            printf("ftw!\n");
            break;
        }

        // prompt for move
        printf("Tile to move: ");
        int tile = get_int();

        // quit if user inputs 0 (for testing)
        if (tile == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // log move (for testing)
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", tile);
        fflush(file);

        // move if possible, else report illegality
        if (!move(tile))
        {
            printf("\nIllegal move.\n");
            usleep(500000);
        }

        // sleep thread for animation's sake
        usleep(500000);
    }

    // close log
    fclose(file);

    // success
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Clears screen using ANSI escape sequences.
 */
void clear(void)
{
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Greets player.
 */
void greet(void)
{
    clear();
    printf("WELCOME TO GAME OF FIFTEEN\n");
    usleep(2000000);
}

/**
 * Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
 * (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).  
 */
void init(void)
{
    int dimensionNum = (d * d) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = dimensionNum--;
        }
    }

    if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        board[d - 1][d - 2] = 2;
        board[d - 1][d - 3] = 1;
    }
}

/**
 * Prints the board in its current state.
 */
void draw(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0) 
            {
                printf("  _");
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("%3i", board[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/**
 * If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
 * returns false. 
 */
bool move(int tile)
{
    int _i, _j; 
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == tile)
            {
                _i = i;
                _j = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if (board[_i + 1][_j] == 0)
    {
        board[_i + 1][_j] = board[_i][_j];
        board[_i][_j] = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else if (board[_i - 1][_j] == 0)
    {
        board[_i - 1][_j] = board[_i][_j];
        board[_i][_j] = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else if (board[_i][_j - 1] == 0)
    {
        board[_i][_j - 1] = board[_i][_j];
        board[_i][_j] = 0;
        return true;
    }
    else if (board[_i][_j + 1] == 0)
    {
        board[_i][_j + 1] = board[_i][_j];
        board[_i][_j] = 0;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: External code dumps are not appreciated here. I suggest preparing the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: `board[_i - 1][_j]`, etc. is not checking that it is in bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you try to find the tile in the board in the move function, you should check if the obtained array indices are valid or not. Because, in case user inputs number outside the permitted values, then some garbage value is used for further condition checking. So make the _i and _j variables -1 or something at the beginning and check if they are - 1 after the for loop in the move function. If they are, it means you have illegal input and can directly return false. Otherwise, you can proceed with the condition checking. Other code seems to be fine. You could also try using the debugger or go through the walkthrough for better understanding.

If this answers your question, click the green checkmark to close this question.